# Neural Network Cost Function Not Minimizing

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, mnist

So I made a simple neural network for MNIST (784 input neurons, 30 hidden neurons, and 10 output neurons), but the cost function (MSE) always increases to 4.5 and never decreases, and the output neurons eventually all just output 1. Here's the code:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

epochs = 50
batch = 60000
learning_rate = 3

B1 = np.random.randn(30, 1)
B2 = np.random.randn(10, 1)

W1 = np.random.randn(784, 30)
W2 = np.random.randn(30, 10)

for i in range(epochs):
    X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)

    c_B1 = np.zeros(B1.shape)
    c_B2 = np.zeros(B2.shape)
    c_W1 = np.zeros(W1.shape)
    c_W2 = np.zeros(W2.shape)

    for b in range(0, np.size(X, 0), batch):
        inputs = X[b:b+batch]
        outputs = Y[b:b+batch]

        Z1 = nn_forward(inputs, W1.T, B1)
        A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
        Z2 = nn_forward(A1, W2.T, B2)
        A2 = sigmoid(Z2)

        e_L = (outputs - A2) * d_sig(Z2)
        e_1 = np.multiply(np.dot(e_L, W2.T), d_sig(Z1))

        d_B2 = np.sum(e_L, axis=0)
        d_B1 = np.sum(e_1, axis=0)

        d_W2 = np.dot(A1.T, e_L)
        d_W1 = np.dot(inputs.T, e_1)

        d_B2 = d_B2.reshape((np.size(B2, 0), 1))
        d_B1 = d_B1.reshape((np.size(B1, 0), 1))

        c_B1 = np.add(c_B1, d_B1)
        c_B2 = np.add(c_B2, d_B2)
        c_W1 = np.add(c_W1, d_W1)
        c_W2 = np.add(c_W2, d_W2)

    B1 = np.subtract(B1, (learning_rate/batch) * c_B1)
    B2 = np.subtract(B2, (learning_rate/batch) * c_B2)
    W1 = np.subtract(W1, (learning_rate/batch) * c_W1)
    W2 = np.subtract(W2, (learning_rate/batch) * c_W2)    

    print(i, cost(outputs, A2))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two things I notice right away:

- Why do you use MSE as loss-function for a classification problem? MSE Is usually used for regression problems. Try using [crossentropy](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html).
- You have sigmoid as output activation, which maps your input `x` to the interval `(0,1)`, so in case you like to do classification you should look at the *argmax* of your output vector and use this as predicted class label.